# Pluralization bug in iOS app: "1 profile views"

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, plurals

I know I need to look out for the giant S, but...

[image: "1 profile views" instead of "1 profile view"]

As you can see, it says "1 profile views" instead of "1 profile view."

- App Version: 1.5.0
- Device: iPhone 4S
- OS Version: Version 9.3.1 (Build 13E238)

Comment: Unimportant people don't get pluralization support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.5.0.2.

Comment: One of the few examples of pluralization errors being fixed, instead of dismissed with the Giant S tweet.

Comment: This is still an [issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306864/339911).